# how to suppress r console output in the pdf using rmarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

Hy Everyone

I am very new to statistics and to r, and I am currently working on a statistics report which is due end of semester...

One thing really troubles me, when I knit my rmarkdown to a pdf, it always shows me two tables, the r console output as well as the "knit asis" output/ shiny.tag.list.

```
#| echo: false
#| results: asis
#| fig.path : knit asis
# descriptive statistics
my_tableone <- 
  CreateTableOne(
    vars = c("gender","work_experience","profession","intent-to-search","leadership_mean",
             "teamwork_mean","workload_mean"),
    data = subset_ecn6y
  )
kableone(
  my_tableone,
  caption = "Descriptive statistics, nurse characteristics, outcome and independent variables"
)
print(my_tableone)
```

[output from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaAIV.png)

Does anyone have some advice? I couldnt find helpful inputs so far...

I tried to change the chunks : result = asis, results = 'hide' but I always get both outputs in the pdf.